# An AJAX/MySQL/PHP question

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So I am working on a registration system for the place I worked at this summer. I have a system where they can "add" things to a basket, but I figured that I also will need to give them the option to delete those items if they so wish. My question comes in here, is there a way to delete a record from the database and update the page in real time? I am using PHP, MySQL, and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adarsh is correct, use an Ajax post:

basic example of your cart page off the top of my head using jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".deleteItem").click(function());
        var dataString = "deleteID="+$(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            url: "deleteScript.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#LI"+$(this)).remove();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <ul>
        <li id="LI1">
            <input type="button" class="deleteItem" id="1"> 1st Item in your cart
        </li>
        <li id="LI2">
            <input type="button" class="deleteItem" id="2"> 2nd Item in your cart
        </li>
        <li id="LI3">
            <input type="button" class="deleteItem" id="3"> 3rd Item in your cart
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Then create the deleteScript.php page to handle the database interaction based on the deleteID you just posted to it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "deleteID="+$(this), what does this do? Shouldn't it be id="+$(this),?

Comment: Also I don't get what this does. $("#LI"+$(this)).remove();

Comment: @Chris The '$("#LI"+$(this)).remove();' remove the item to delete from the list(It removes the <li> with the id LI?). The 'var dataString = "deleteID="+$(this);' and the ajax function must be inside the click handler($(".deleteItem").click(function());). The example have some errors but it's a start.

Comment: @Chris For the firs comment, it can be 'deleteId' or 'id', it depends on how you named the variable in your delete function.

Comment: $(this) represents the itme that was clicked.

Comment: Actually, that'is incomplete, it should be $(this).attr("id") now you have the id to pass your php script to delete from the database

Comment: Also I am filling a HTML table dynamically from the database so I am grabbing some ids from the database and using them to distinguish the buttons that I am using to delete the items from the database. Which I am sure complicates this a bit more.

Comment: My question is now how do I remove things from a dynamically created HTML table? I am assuming it has something to do with the success function and an id, but the id would be the same for all the table rows. Sorry for all the questions, but I am just learning jQuery, I decided it was finally time to learn it.

Comment: @Chris It has nothing to do with Jquery but with PHP. Just put the id of the item dynamically in the row. ex : <tr id="id-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">. And do the same when you call the function. ex: click="deleteItem(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)". Maybe you should ask this in a new question.

Comment: @elblanco I just asked it in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use AJAX to fire a query to delete the item and once your method returns, update and clear the item from your basket.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file which deletes items (e.g. delete-item.php?id=X&user_id=X,) and then reload their list of items. It should be as easy as that.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up being a the way I went for other people that see this with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for here is an AJAX solution that will `POST` an HTTP request to your server that results in a DELETE operation on your database.

The simplest way to do this is with one of the many AJAX frameworks out there, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/).

It is **vital** that you do this with an HTTP `POST` and not a `GET` (which is what a simple link would do), because `GET` requests should **never** have a side-effect to their main function of retrieving data from a server.

You might want to Google the term `CRUD` (Create, Read, Update, Delete) along with HTTP to get some insight into this. Or just [click here](http://www.google.com/search?q=CRUD+HTTP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) to save finger-work

Comment: I am using jQuery as stated in the original question. Thanks though.

Comment: Duly noted... but others may not be, so I wanted to include a few other options.